# Android Get data or table webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services

i watched too many videos about android webservises
but all them results finished error
"java.net.SocketTimeoutException"
i used
"ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar"

can you guide me on this

my codes ;

```
package com.example.acr_soaptest2;
import android.util.Log;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
        import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class ServiceManager {
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "MySQl_Query";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/MySQl_Query";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8090/WebService1.asmx";

    SoapObject soapObject;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope;
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE;
    public void PushData(String query) {
        soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        soapObject.addProperty("sorgu", query);
        soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        soapSerializationEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

        httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpTransportSE.debug = true;
        try {
            httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapSerializationEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive=(SoapPrimitive)soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println(soapPrimitive.toString());
            Log.d("satir:", soapPrimitive.toString());
                   } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("satir:", ex.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Firstly, you should add your code!

Comment: Without the faulty code, we cannot troubleshoot for you. Please kindly attach minimal code snippets and stacktrace where this exception is thrown in your app.